Camel routes and jms configuration not getting resolved in xml file
I am using XML-DSL for my Camel code. I am not making use of any framework like Spring or Spring-Boot.The below is my camel-context.xml file.
<camel>
  <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans">
    <bean id="jmsConfiguration" class="com.test.config.JMSConfiguration">
      <constructor-arg name="url" value="${JMS.JNDI.SERVER.URL}"/>
      <constructor-arg name="username" value="${JMS.JNDI.USERNAME}"/>
      <constructor-arg name="password" value="${JMS.JNDI.PASSWORD}"/>
    </bean>
    <bean id="jmsConnectionFactory" factory-bean="JMSConfiguration" factory-method="createConnectionFactory"/>
    <bean id="ems" class="org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsComponent">
      <property name="connectionFactory" ref="jmsConnectionFactory"/>
    </bean>

  <import resource="classpath:routes/*.xml"/>
</camel>

The JMSConfiguration is a java code.
The route is a basic route as below :
<route id="TestEvents">
        <from uri="jms:queue:TestService"/>
        <log message="Message received"/>
        <transform>
            <constant>{ "status": "ok (from mock)" }</constant>
        </transform>
    </route>


The application is not able to load the route on startup as well the jms connection.
Please suggest.

